# Visual Studio 2013 to 2015 migration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We are interested in migrating our environment from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015. We have several solutions with a large number of projects (about 100).

We use a custom .props file with conditional properties to change things like include directories and output paths as appropriate for the two versions. The resulting converted Visual Studio 2015 project files are identical except for the Project ToolsVersion and the PlatformToolset settings.

Ideally I would like to have project files that are compatible with both versions during the migration progress. Is this possible?

The alternative is to create separate 2015 copies of all the project files, but the maintenance of those would be unfortunate. Am I missing another possible better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I was able to get projects to be compatible with building on Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 simultaneously.

I manually edited the project file to include these lines instead of the normal `PlatformToolset` entry. The `Project` `ToolsVersion` doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
<PlatformToolset Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='12.0'">v120</PlatformToolset>
<PlatformToolset Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='14.0'">v140</PlatformToolset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass some values of variables to MSBuild command line when building your projects on CI. It's classic scenario when there is a neccesity to build several configurations of same project.

Usually parameters such as "PlatformToolset" are encapsulated in different configurations (Release VC++12/Release VC++14 for example), and the desired configuration is specified when invoking MSBuild (the concrete scenario depends on the CI software you use).

The "ToolsVersion" is about MSBuild version used in build process (NOT a compiler/linker versions!), and in most situations you can use only one version for all your configurations. So, just stay with the most recent version of MSBuild you have access to at your build/developer machines.

Answer (score 0):

We use pretty sophisticated building configs and currently develop simultaneously using VS2012, 2013 and 2015. Moving to 2015 forced us to some minor code changes (it became more restrictive at some points), but except that we have encountered no issues.

There are some unnecessary changes to .csproj or .sln files, but it is was basically a VS signature and causes nothing more than mess on source control :) VS2012 opens 2015 edited projects without problems.